# Create meshgrids from 2D slices off 3D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 3D numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
print(X)

[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]]
```

I would like to vectorize the following for all 2D array in 3D array. For example, for 1st 2D array:

```
ss = np.array(np.meshgrid(*X[0]), dtype=object).T.reshape(-1,2)
print(ss)

[[0 3]
 [0 4]
 [0 5]
 [1 3]
 [1 4]
 [1 5]
 [2 3]
 [2 4]
 [2 5]]
```

I tried following:

```
def f(x):
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*x), dtype=object).T.reshape(-1,2)

ff = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, X)
print(ff)
```

Comment: What would be your typical second axis shape .i.e. `X.shape[1]`? In fact, what would be your typical `X.shape`?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to achieve that:

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
out = np.stack(np.broadcast_arrays(X[:, 0, :, None], X[:, 1, None, :]), -1).reshape(len(X), -1, 2)
print(out)
# [[[ 0  3]
#   [ 0  4]
#   [ 0  5]
#   [ 1  3]
#   [ 1  4]
#   [ 1  5]
#   [ 2  3]
#   [ 2  4]
#   [ 2  5]]
# 
#  [[ 6  9]
#   [ 6 10]
#   [ 6 11]
#   [ 7  9]
#   [ 7 10]
#   [ 7 11]
#   [ 8  9]
#   [ 8 10]
#   [ 8 11]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic solution that uses one-loop and scales to generic shapes. It assigns into an initialized array and broadcasts to replicate values, where it achieves memory efficiency. It works for any length along the second axis of `X`. Hence, the implementation would be -

```
def meshgrid_2D_blocks(X):
    m,n,r = X.shape
    out_shp = [m]+[r]*n+[n]
    out = np.empty(out_shp,dtype=X.dtype)

    # Assign each block iteratively
    shp = [-1]+[1]*n
    for i in range(n):
        shp[i+1] = r
        out[...,i] = X[:,i].reshape(shp)
        shp[i+1] = 1
    return out.reshape(m,-1,n)
```

**Sample runs**

Case #1 : Second axis of `length=2`

```
In [167]: X = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)

In [168]: X
Out[168]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])

In [169]: meshgrid_2D_blocks(X)
Out[169]: 
array([[[ 0,  3],
        [ 0,  4],
        [ 0,  5],
        [ 1,  3],
        [ 1,  4],
        [ 1,  5],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 2,  5]],

       [[ 6,  9],
        [ 6, 10],
        [ 6, 11],
        [ 7,  9],
        [ 7, 10],
        [ 7, 11],
        [ 8,  9],
        [ 8, 10],
        [ 8, 11]]])
```

Case #2 : Second axis of `length=3`

```
In [170]: X = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 3, 2)

In [171]: X
Out[171]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])

In [172]: meshgrid_2D_blocks(X)
Out[172]: 
array([[[ 0,  2,  4],
        [ 0,  2,  5],
        [ 0,  3,  4],
        [ 0,  3,  5],
        [ 1,  2,  4],
        [ 1,  2,  5],
        [ 1,  3,  4],
        [ 1,  3,  5]],

       [[ 6,  8, 10],
        [ 6,  8, 11],
        [ 6,  9, 10],
        [ 6,  9, 11],
        [ 7,  8, 10],
        [ 7,  8, 11],
        [ 7,  9, 10],
        [ 7,  9, 11]]])
```